# How to add active class in dayClick event of dnCalendar?

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am using dnCalendar to fetch events for every day using dayClick event. **github Reference is** : [dnCalendar](https://github.com/black-lotus/dnCalendar). I am doing ajax call & fetching HTML response and appending to HTML page till now this is fine but **My problem here is** I am unable to add 'active' class to a date currently clicked in the calendar. If I try with below code then it is **showing the error in console as** "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined**"

I have Tried below code:

```
dayClick: function(date, view, event) {
 $(".note").removeClass("note");
 $(event.target).addClass("note"); 
}
```

showing the error in console as: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined**

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var my_calendar = $("#dncalendar-container").dnCalendar({
    minDate: "2016-01-15",
    maxDate: "2100-12-31",
    monthNames: [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ],
    monthNamesShort: [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mey', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ],
    dayNames: [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ],
    dayNamesShort: [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ],
    notes: [ ],
    showNotes: true,
    startWeek: 'monday',
    dayClick: function(date, view, event) {
      $(".note").removeClass("note"); // I added these first 2 lines to add 'note' as my active class
      $(event.target).addClass("note");
      var eDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
      $.ajax({
         url: "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/ajax/getSingleEventData",
         type: "POST",
         data: {e_date : eDate},
         success: function(response){
           console.log(response);
           $("#eventsHTML").html('');
           $('.show_calenderData').hide();
           $("#eventsHTML").html(response);
         }
      });    
     }
   });
   my_calendar.build();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="block calender_box">
                    <div id="dncalendar-container"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="block calender_content text-left">
                      <div id="eventsHTML">
                       ------------
                       ------------
                      </div> <!-- id="eventsHTML" -->
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- class="row" -->
            </div> <!-- class="col-md-7" -->
</div> <!-- class="row" -->
```

Here in my case 'active' class means 'note' class. Can anyone Please tell How to add active class to the clicked date? Thanks.

Comment: $(this).addClass("note");

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried it, If I click on multiple dates the class for previous date remains the same. Actually previous date class has to be removed and the class for current date only should be active.

Comment: To remove the other classes, try `$("#dncalendar-container").find(".note").removeClass("note");`

Comment: Javascript error in the console as "
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token", as a result not showing the total calendar in the webpage.

Comment: nop this simple one worked fine `$(".note").removeClass("note");` Thanks Mr. Louys Patrice Bessette

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var my_calendar = $("#dncalendar-container").dnCalendar({
    minDate: "2016-01-15",
    maxDate: "2100-12-31",
    monthNames: [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ],
    monthNamesShort: [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mey', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ],
    dayNames: [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ],
    dayNamesShort: [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ],
    notes: [{date: "2018-8-14"},{date: "2018-8-15"},{date: "2018-8-16"}],
    showNotes: true,
    startWeek: 'monday',
    dayClick: function(date, view, event) {
      $(".note").removeClass("note"); // I added these first 2 lines to add 'note' as my active class
      $(event.target).addClass("note");
      var eDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
      $.ajax({
         url: "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/ajax/getSingleEventData",
         type: "POST",
         data: {e_date : eDate},
         success: function(response){
           console.log(response);
           $("#eventsHTML").html('');
           $('.show_calenderData').hide();
           $("#eventsHTML").html(response);
         }
      });    
     }
   });
   my_calendar.build();
});

> Blockquote

**And for day Click you can do like this**
```

Comment: dayClick: function(date, view) {
           jQuery('#dncalendar-body tr td div.blue-click').removeClass('blue-click');
           jQuery('#dncalendar-container .default-date').removeClass('default-date');
              jQuery(this).children().addClass('blue-click');